# How to use socket.io-client in angular 8 to get acknowledgement

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets

Server side is nodejs socket.io and I have connected to Angular socket.io-client. I trying to an acknowledgement when emitting an event . If anyone know any documentation or tutorial how I can do it, please help

Comment: Please share some of your code and explain the problem thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, simply pass a function as the last parameter of .send or .emit. What’s more, when you use .emit, the acknowledgement is done by you, which means you can also pass data along:
[Source Link](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements)
Your server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.on('ferret', function (name, word, fn) {
    fn(name + ' says ' + word);
 });
});
```

Your Client.js

```
 socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', 'woot', function (data) { // args are sent in order to acknowledgement function
      console.log(data); // data will be 'tobi says woot'
   });
 });
```